# Function url missing after deployment in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

[image: screenshot of deployment error]

I am trying to deploy an `index.js` file in the `dialogflow`. so when I finish the steps if the deployment I am supposed to receive a Project `Console` and a `Function Url`. This function `url` is supposed to be added to the Fulfillment `url` to get the `chatbot` running. But I receive only the Project console as can been seen in the screenshot attached.

Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of the Firebase tools and try again.

Comment: I have used " npm install -g firebase-tools" for firebase tools installation. I guessed it must be the latest version. Is there any other method i should try ?

Comment: The URL should also listed in the Firebase console.

Comment: Yes. I got it. thanks a lot.